# Can't run my project error in "run" debug file included

Tags: java, gluon

am using last version of gluonhq also i try some other versions . my problem is when i try to run the project , if someone know the solve of it note that am using the demo version i got the following msg:

> Executing external task 'run'...
>   :compileJava
>   :processResources
>   :classes
>   :compileDesktopJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :processDesktopResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :desktopClasses UP-TO-DATE
>   :run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':run'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073740791

[The Debug log here](https://paste.sh/TtH83d1w#v4bIf4ueJ7_O-bCEBUdsnbXi)

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file? Can you run `gradlew --info run` and see if it works? Otherwise post the log

Comment: this is the build log :
https://paste.ubuntu.com/23907390/

the stackrace run log:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/23907400/

the gradlew --info run log:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/23907403/

Comment: The project is created with the Gluon plugin for IntelliJ? Have you modified it? Try running first `gradlew clean build` and see if it end successfully. Then run it again. Also from IntelliJ try to clean/build/run it (open the Gradle Window and select the tasks). When you open the project, does it show any error?

Comment: Do you have nVidia graphic card, with drivers recently updated? See this [thread](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299218/minecraft-keep-crashing-game-ended-with-bad-state-exit-code-1073740791), they are reporting the same error.

Comment: Hello jose,
Thank you for your kindly answers , the first answer fix my issue in mac and the second which is talk about nVidia fix my issue in windows , so both answers good with me and do what am looking for .

My pleasure.